# Proof improvement for $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2)(g^2+h^2) = A^2 + B^2$ given $(a+ib)(c+id)(e+if)(g+ih) = A + iB$

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof

If $(a+ib)(c+id)(e+if)(g+ih) = A + iB$, prove that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2)(g^2+h^2) = A^2 + B^2$

My approach is pretty straightforward:

$$(a+ib)(c+id)(e+if)(g+ih)$$
$$((ac-bd)+i(ad+bc))(e+if)(g+ih)$$
$$(x+iy)(e+if)(g+ih)$$
$$((xe-yf)+i(xf+ye))(g+ih)$$
$$(u+iv)(g+ih)$$

At this point we can see that

$$A = ug-vh$$
$$B = uh+vg$$

$$A^2 + B^2 = (ug-vh)^2+(uh+vg)^2$$
And now you simply recursively unfold the above to get the desired result.

I can't shake the feeling that i'm missing something though. Maybe it's some extra step in my solution or maybe there's a much simpler solution.

Comment: This is also able to be proven using Lagrange's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity  on the closure of the set of the sums of squares. It is also related to the proof that all primes factorable in the gaussian integers (those congruent to one modulo four) are able to be written as the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, we have $$|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$$
So,
$$(a+ib)(c+id)(e+if)(g+ih) = A + iB$$
$$|(a+ib)(c+id)(e+if)(g+ih)| = |A + iB|$$
$$|(a+ib)||(c+id)||(e+if)||(g+ih)| = |A + iB|$$
$$(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})(\sqrt{c^2+d^2})(\sqrt{e^2+f^2})(\sqrt{g^2+h^2}) = (\sqrt{A^2+B^2})$$
Thus
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2)(g^2+h^2) = (A^2+B^2)$$